# Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2

[image: Error screenshot]
Can't understand how to fix it and why it appears?

```
    Ld /Users/atencion/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flylista-gcadfttyrgznkmafzaicacwytfey/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flylista.app/Flylista normal i386
    cd "/Users/atencion/Documents/Applications Development/Xcode Projects/Flylista"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/atencion/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flylista-gcadfttyrgznkmafzaicacwytfey/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/atencion/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flylista-gcadfttyrgznkmafzaicacwytfey/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/atencion/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flylista-gcadfttyrgznkmafzaicacwytfey/Build/Intermediates/Flylista.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flylista.build/Objects-normal/i386/Flylista.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000 -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/atencion/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flylista-gcadfttyrgznkmafzaicacwytfey/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flylista.app/Flylista

ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlightsViewController in /Users/atencion/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flylista-gcadfttyrgznkmafzaicacwytfey/Build/Intermediates/Flylista.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flylista.build/Objects-normal/i386/FlightViewController.o and /Users/atencion/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flylista-gcadfttyrgznkmafzaicacwytfey/Build/Intermediates/Flylista.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flylista.build/Objects-normal/i386/FlightsViewController.o for architecture i386
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you try the clean the whole project?

Comment: Yes, also removed derived data.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The actual error is right there in front of you. It appears that your link phase is failing due to a duplicate symbol: `FlightsViewController`. You've probably defined this twice, or perhaps you've linked it into a library as well as into your main build.

Comment: @shim: you fix it by not having multiple definitions of the same symbol.

Comment: well I got the same error once when I accidentally included a "viewController.m" instead of "viewController.h". Sometimes A bit of Hurry..accompanies a lot of worry!!

Answer (score 1):

This can also commonly happen when you copy/duplicate classes. Make sure you don't have any constants defined in your duplicated class that may be defined elsewhere, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution

When you are working on an iOS application say iPhone or iPad but you have selected wrongly

"My Mac 64 bit" you will get this error [image]

So select proper application type say

iphone Retina(3.5 inch)
device
iphone Retina(4 inch)
iphone Retina 64 bit

ipad
ipad retina

etc then you will not get this error.