# Getting libtool failed with exit code 1 error. What do i do?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, xcode4.3

The exact error is :
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1

```
Libtool /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RWACommon-asaaevxqjainigcczkcvgrxvpyyp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RWACommon.framework/Versions/A/RWACommon normal i386
cd /Users/dkatz/Sites/xCode/RWA/RWACommon
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only i386 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RWACommon-asaaevxqjainigcczkcvgrxvpyyp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RWACommon-asaaevxqjainigcczkcvgrxvpyyp/Build/Intermediates/RWACommon.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RWACommon.build/Objects-normal/i386/RWACommon.LinkFileList -framework MessageUI -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreText -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework GData -o /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RWACommon-asaaevxqjainigcczkcvgrxvpyyp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RWACommon.framework/Versions/A/RWACommon
```

Thanks guys. (I am using xcode 4.3 btw)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this solution that i have provided you at the following link

[Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405053/command-developer-platforms-iphonesimulator-platform-developer-usr-bin-clang-fa/20489888#20489888)