# I don't get it: "linker command failed with exit code 1" error

Tags: ios5, storyboard, xcode4.3

Last week I was working on a project. Today, I reopened the project and tried to build it again. But I received an error message. I don't understand why I got this message because I didn't change anything of the project. (I'm using XCode 4.3 with storyboards)

```
Ld /Users/mete/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MySınav-ceckdqzcfyfgicaqrhloynhdnglw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MySınav.app/MySınav normal i386
cd /Users/mete/Documents/MySınav
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/mete/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MySınav-ceckdqzcfyfgicaqrhloynhdnglw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/mete/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MySınav-ceckdqzcfyfgicaqrhloynhdnglw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/mete/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MySınav-ceckdqzcfyfgicaqrhloynhdnglw/Build/Intermediates/MySınav.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MySınav.build/Objects-normal/i386/MySınav.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -lsqlite3 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/mete/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MySınav-ceckdqzcfyfgicaqrhloynhdnglw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MySınav.app/MySınav

ld: duplicate symbol _counter in /Users/mete/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MySınav-ceckdqzcfyfgicaqrhloynhdnglw/Build/Intermediates/MySınav.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MySınav.build/Objects-normal/i386/examPaused.o and /Users/mete/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MySınav-ceckdqzcfyfgicaqrhloynhdnglw/Build/Intermediates/MySınav.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MySınav.build/Objects-normal/i386/examSelf.o for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear - you have two global symbols with the same name (`_counter`) defined in both examPaused.o and `examSelf.o`. This can happen because you have two global variables or non-static functions with the same name defined separately, or more commonly when you define something in a header file which then gets included/imported into two or more source files.

Comment: I've mistakenly imported same class's .h and .m files into another class at the same time. Problem solved. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, mete, I used FBGraph API,

Error:
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJSON in /Users/sumitgosh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BoleApp-avgexapsugmcsaexkijxcnqktmdx/Build/Intermediates/BoleApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BoleApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/SBJSON-6C85BADD94574567.o and /Users/sumitgosh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BoleApp-avgexapsugmcsaexkijxcnqktmdx/Build/Intermediates/BoleApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BoleApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/SBJSON-58E23D7C54AF5087.o for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Can you tell me, where i will get this SBJSON-58E23D7C54AF5087.o and SBJSON-6C85BADD94574567.o file in my project... ??

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this solution that i have provided you at the following link.This can help you

[Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405053/command-developer-platforms-iphonesimulator-platform-developer-usr-bin-clang-fa/20489888#20489888)